# Завершение цикла при повторном вводе слова. Python

Tags: python, циклы, while

Нужно, чтобы ввод слов заканчивался, если пользователь вводит одно и то же слово дважды подряд. Вроде бы код рабочий, но не до конца... Спасибо.

Например:

Введите слово: человек

Введите слово: планета

Введите слово: машина

Введите слово: робот

Введите слово: робот

Человек планета машина робот

Вот мой код:

```
t = 0 
s = ""
while True:
    w = input("Введите слово: ")
    if w=="конец" :
        complete = True
        break  
    elif w != "конец":
        complete=False
    s += w + " "
    t += 1  

if complete:
    print(s)
```

Comment: Почему у тебя w=="конец"? Где в твоем условии вообще про слово "Конец" хоть что то? По идее тебе нужно в изначально пустую переменную z делать if w == z: ... else w = z. Ты в z хранишь предыдущее слово. Если вдруг предыдущее и новое слова совпадают, оно делает break. Ну и заполняешь переменную через +=. И еще, что делает t?

Comment: Спасибо !!! Твой ответ помог! Я подправил код и получилось !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверь, все ли работает так, как ты себе представляешь?:

```
s = ""
z = ""
while True:
    w = input("Введите слово: ")
    if w == z:
        break
    else:
        z = w
        s += w + " "

print(s)
```

```
Введите слово: человек
Введите слово: планета
Введите слово: машина
Введите слово: робот
Введите слово: робот
человек планета машина робот
```